# Can't inject EntityManager,HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

```
 DaoImp.java      


package com.ujjwol.daoImp;  
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import com.ujjwol.dao.UserDao;
    import com.ujjwol.model.User;
    @Repository
    public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
        @Override
        public void createUser(User user) {
            entityManager.persist(user);        
        }

        @Override
        public User readUser(User user) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUser(User user) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void deleteUser(User user) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public List<User> readAllUser() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>

            <!--Hibernate properties-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ujjwol</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <name>Demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>




    <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


    <!-- - Mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->



        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>


        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <annotation-driven />


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ujjwol.controller"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ujjwol.serviceImp"></context:component-scan>
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.ujjwol.daoImp"></context:component-scan>
</beans:beans>








  May 05, 2016 9:21:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/demo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ujjwol.daoImp.UserDaoImp.createUser(UserDaoImp.java:23)
        at com.ujjwol.serviceImp.UserServiceImp.createUser(UserServiceImp.java:23)
        at com.ujjwol.controller.UserController.saveUser(UserController.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Everything is working well,But when i try to connect to the database and call DaoImp(Can't inject EntityManager). then the program is concluded with the above listed error:** 
I have checked all my Service class, Everything is okay. 
I am trying to learn java framework. (Beginner)

Comment: Could be several issues.  First, is your container (e.g. ApplicationContext) constructing the UserDaoImp, or are you constructing it yourself?  Second, it's possible it is being constructed by Spring but not injected because Spring doesn't have an EntityManagerFactory (I don't see it in your application context).  Third, it is possible Spring has the EMF but not injecting the EM because you don't have a transaction.

Comment: @Pace UserDaoImp is for injecting beans . .I am trying with EntityManager instead of EMF.Can you suggest me the solution please

Comment: How do you get a reference to your UserDaoImpl?  Do you have `new UserDaoImpl()` in your code somewhere?  Or do you have `applicationContext.getBean(UserDaoImpl.class)`?  Or is it wired into some other class?  Or do you get a reference to it some other way?

Comment: I used autowired annotation for UserDaoImp  @pace

Comment: Ok.  Does your application context have an EntityManagerFactory?  I don't see it in the one you posted.

Comment: I  am trying  to use EntityManager

Comment: Your application context will still need an entity manager factory although you don't ever need to reference it in your code.  When Spring sees the `@PersistenceContext` annotation it searches the application context for an entity manager factory which it uses to generate entity managers to inject.  Take a look at the application context on this example: https://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/ Specifically the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: Thanx . I will try

Comment: Can you please help me with the code:<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
        p:username="root" p:password="" p:initialSize="5" p:maxActive="10">
    </bean>
 
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

Comment: Since i have already initialized the database code(jdbc driver, url ,pw etc) in persistence.xml. Do i need to re-write the codes in  servlet-context.xml too? And how do i create  EntityManagerFactory beans in  servlet-context. Do you have sample code?

Comment: If you have a persistence.xml file in the right place then all you need to do is set the `persistenceUnitName` property on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.  You can skip the `dataSource` property.  You do still need the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` however.  I don't have any examples handy at the moment.

Comment: Why can't i write dependency for spring orm?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

Comment: a small red cross appears at my project as i write dependency for spring orm.

Comment: Do you have a property in your maven file named `org.springframework.version`?

Comment: <org.springframework-version>4.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  This is my property in my pom.xml